# "Undefined variable : main" in pydev/python

Tags: python, pydev, program-entry-point

I made a file named "Main" in pydev and inside it wrote:

```
if  __name__ =='__Main__':
    main()

def main():
    print("jargon")
```

It says my call to main() under the if statement contains an undefined variable and won't compile. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python code is executed top-to-bottom.  You need to move your `main()` definition above the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.  The way you have it, at the time that you try to call `main()`, the function does not yet exist.

Comment: I see. Since Java is bottom-up would a Jython interpreter execute bottom-up or top-bottom?

Comment: It will still be top down, since Jython code is Python source, not Java, so it follows the rules of the Python language.